# Accent keys not working as expected on macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, keyboard, ventura

I speak and type in Russian but occasionally I need to type some words in the Kyrgyz language. The alphabet is the same as Russian's but with three additional letters.

Up until macOS Ventura, holding down keys <kbd>о</kbd>, <kbd>у</kbd>, <kbd>н</kbd> in the Russian PC input source would give me a menu with accent letters that contained needed Kyrgyz letters "ө", "ү", "ң". That was incredibly convenient for me because to get these letters in Kyrgyz layout you need to also hold down <kbd>Opt</kbd> which is very inconvenient.

In macOS Ventura, the behavior changed. It's not as if it completely stopped working, it started behaving as an iOS keyboard. Almost all accent keys are gone except for "ё" and "ъ".
How can I roll back the behavior to the old one? Having plenty of options in accent keys was incredibly convenient.

Comment: Have you checked the keyboard maps?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that you have the correct Keyboard Layout selected?

Comment: Exactly whiich of the Russian keyboards provided by Apple are you using?  I could post you the Monterey version.

Comment: @benwiggy yes, I am absolutely sure that I use the correct layout

Comment: @SolarMike what keyboard maps are you talking about? I don't use any keyboard mapping applications, if that's what you mean

Comment: @TomGewecke I use the standard "Russian PC" layout that comes with macOS. I tried the simple "Russian" layout, but still no accents . And yes, I would be very grateful if you could post the Monterey version.

Answer (score 3):

The Monterey version of the Russian PC layout can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xklf7x2op7bklfp/Russian%20PC%20Copy.bundle.zip?dl=0).

But it's not the layout but a [keyboard-ru.plist in the Press and Hold app](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/custom-characters-accent-popup-osx/) which you probably need.  You can get that [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oj98qcraygqojj5/Keyboard-ru.plist.zip?dl=0).  Whether there is any way to insert this .plist or edit the existing one in Ventura I don't know.

Apple has moved the location of this .plist in Ventura. Now it appears to be in /System/Library/TextInput/TextInput_ru.bundle/Versions/A/Resources/Keyboard-ru.plist

If modifying that turns out to be impractical, perhaps best to use [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) to add the characters you need to a custom Russian PC keyboard.